# Javascript callback handler in WebView for Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, webview, webview-flutter

I'm using the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package for displaying local HTML + JS content in my flutter app. I'm using the `addJavaScriptChannel` method of the WebViewController to communicate with the HTML app. This is working fine for Android/iOS.
But for Flutter Web, this is not working. I'm getting an unimplemented error.

I can use [webview_flutter_web](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_web) for displaying the content on Flutter Web, but it does not provide the functionality to communicate with Javascript.

Is there any way to add javascript channel to a flutter Web's webview?